# PendingServiceRouting records reporting and queries

Tags: reporting, omnichannel

Looking for a way to report on our Skills Backlog so we can see most needed skill (for example: Skill X is on 20 unassigned work items in the backlog).  Can report on PendingServiceRouting, but can not find a way to retrieve the skills associated to the record.

Answer (score 0):

How did you report on PendingServiceRouting?

Skills are in SkillRequirement object, RelatedRecordId is the PendingServiceRouting Id.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_skillrequirement.htm